# codeigniter URI routing issue: output as $1 rather than the name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to achieve something like this:

> example.com/profile/abc

but the following piece of code gives me the output as
**$1** rather than the profile name. Here - for example - the output of variable **$name** should be **abc** but the output is **$1**

**Controller**

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
   public function get_profile($name)
   {
    echo $name;
   }
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
$route['profile/:any'] = "profile/get_profile/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the correct syntax

**change**

```
$route['profile/:any'] = "profile/get_profile/$1";
```

**to**

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = "profile/get_profile/$1";
```